# Unable to access session on JSP

Tags: jsp-tags, struts-1, netbiscuits

I have a JSP with netbiscuits code in it, I am now removing that netbiscuits code but after removing I am unable to get session from my previous page due to which I am unable to move ahead. I am using struts 1. Please suggest a solution to my problem, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without any code, it's impossible to help. The session is an implicit object on *every* JSP page, so it's not because you can't access the session itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your problem.

Can you explain it little more?

Usually for accessing session in jsp pages we use the code with in scriptlets like

```
String x=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");
```

Type casting is required.
or use

```
String x=""+session.getAttribute("uname");
```

If you want to print it somewhere in the jsp page do,

```
<%= session.getAttribute("uname")%>
```

It will print the session value in jsp page.

otherwise use like

```
 <% String x=""+session.getAttribute("uname"); %>
 <%=x %>
```

For accessing in java pages

```
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
String uname=""+session.get("uname");
```